# viewForAnnotation Is Not Getting Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, annotations

Having scanned all the similar problems and tried all possible solutions, I still can't find the solution to my case. I tried to put multiple pins on my **MapView** but it seems that my pin can't be added normally. I started a **NSTimer** in my **viewDidLoad** method so that every 5 seconds, some  updated pins will be put on Map. I added debugging information and found the problem was the that the method viewForAnnotation is not getting called. 
(I've already set the delegate by calling **[_map setDelegate:self]**)

My code is as following:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] frame]];
        [_map setDelegate:self];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D startLocation;
        startLocation.latitude = [startLat floatValue];
        startLocation.longitude = [startLong floatValue];
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.002, 0.002);
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(startLocation, span);
        [_map setRegion:region];

        [[self view] addSubview:_map];

        [self getPlacesForLocation:[_map centerCoordinate]];

        NSTimer *currentTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self  selector:@selector(theActionMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [currentTimer fire];
   }
```

**The getPlacesForLocationMethod:**

```
-(void)getPlacesForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location
{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                   {

                       /*  get data from the website 
                       **  get the geo information and put them in the MapPin struct
                       */

                       [self putPinsOnMap];
                   }
}
```

**putPinsOnMap:**

```
-(void)putPinsOnMap
{

    for(Pinfo *iter in [_PinfoArray copy])
    {
        MapPin *pin = [[MapPin alloc] init];
        [pin setTitle:[iter from_user_name]];
        [pin setSubtitle:[iter text]];
        [pin setCoordinate:[iter location]];

        //NSLog(@"The coordinate is %f  %f", [pin coordinate].latitude, [pin coordinate].longitude);

        [_map addAnnotation:pin];

        /****************************************/

        NSLog(@"Try to put the pin on Map");
        /****************************************/
    }
}
```

And here is the content of my **MapPin.h**:

```
@interface MapPin : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title, *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

If I stay in place, then every time the **(void)putPinsOnMap** gets called, it prints **"Try to put pin on Map"** but the **viewForAnnotation** method is not getting called (I also added debugging info there but none of them are printed). Only a few times, the method **viewForAnnotation** sometimes will be called if I zoom out to a great extent.

Answer (score 1):

You say you added debugging info to viewForAnnotation, but you haven't subclassed MKMapView to override the viewForAnnotation method (or at least, you are allocating an MKMapView, not any subclass).  I think you are looking for the delegate method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

and if you implement that method in your view controller (which you are making the delegate of the MKMapView) you might get useful information.

If mapView:viewForAnnotation: is still not called except when you zoom way out then you have probably placed your annotations incorrectly and they're just way out on some other part of the globe than the one you have initially on screen.

Comment: Actually I have already implemented this method, it still doesn't work. And the debugging information was added to this method, that's why I said the debugging information in this method is not printed in console.

Comment: The code you've posted looks mostly OK.  I'm a little suspicious of "theActionMethod," but you say putPinsOnMap is getting called, so did you copy/paste from an older version of viewDidLoad?  Why don't you post your implementation of mapView:viewForAnnotation.  The problem could be in that method.